# Error: undefined reference to `sigar_open@4' In Sigar C++

Tags: c++, sigar

Hi i m using sigar library for developing an application in c++. but unfortunately i m unable just start.... i m using following starting basic code but getting Error: undefined reference to `sigar_open@4'.

This is code i m using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "sigar.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "sigar_format.h"

}
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int status, i;
    sigar_t *sigar;
    sigar_cpu_list_t cpulist;

    sigar_open(&sigar);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to get start...........

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: This error generate when i call "sigar_open(&sigar)"..............

Comment: To clarify, the SO link above is also titled, "What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?"  Your question will likely get marked as a duplicate.